# how to use trino/presto to query redis

Tags: redis, presto, trino

I have a simple string and hash stored in redis

```
get test
"1"

hget htest first
"first hash"
```

I'm able to see the "table" test, but there are no columns

```
trino> show columns from redis.default.test;
  Column | Type | Extra | Comment
  --------+------+-------+---------
  (0 rows)
```

and obviously I can't get result from select

```
trino> select * from redis.default.test;
  Query 20210918_174414_00006_dmp3x failed: line 1:8: SELECT * not allowed from relation 
   that has no columns
```

I see in the documentation that I might need to create a table definition file, but I wasn't able to create one that will work.
I had few variations of this, but this is the one for example:

```
{
"tableName": "test",
"schemaName": "default",
"value": {
    "dataFormat": "json",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "number",
            "mapping": 0,
            "type": "INT"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

any idea what am I doing wrong?

I focused on the string since it's simpler, but I also need to query the hash

Comment: I found your same post in community Slack. Replied in https://trinodb.slack.com/archives/CGB0QHWSW/p1632044171270000